# I need get file via AJAX or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

If I have file on the server and I need parse this file. For parsing I will use JavaScript. Do I have to use AJAX which will call JavaScript which will parsing document and will return results  or I can get the file directly via JavaScript without AJAX?

The results will appear in same web page where user will enter request for parsing.

Now, I parse document via Perl and use AJAX.

```
 $.ajax({
   url: "parse_log.pl",
   dataType: "json",
   method: "GET",
   success: function(result){
  console.log(result);
```

If I script changed to JavaSript I have to use AJAX or I can use only JavaScript which will not only parse file but also display results on the web page.

Thanks.

Comment: AJAX is just a name for an API that fetches URLs in JS code.  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Are you trying to include a JavaScript in in your JavaScript file? What format is the file you're trying to parse?

Comment: @MCMXCII File is format text. I have script (JavaScript) which parsing the file and I want show the results of the script on the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's rather confusing what you're asking but i'll try to help.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "parse_log.pl",
    dataType: "application/json",
    method: "GET",
    success: result => console.log(result), //will log back the result (stringified)
    error: err => console.log(err)
 });
```

When you make an ajax call you're sending a request to the server for some data. The server can't just send you the data as is, it has to stringify it, and it will send you back a stringified object, or in other words, JSON. On your javascript file, assuming you have done this correctly, and the sever did not error out or something else, will return to you the json as the argument you define in your function, in your case 'result'.

```
$.ajax({
   url: "parse_log.pl",
   dataType: "application/json",
   method: "GET",
   success: result => {
            let data = JSON.parse(result)

   },
   error: err => err
```

So the server sends back the stringified object, which you then have to parse for use, using JSON.parse.  Now you should be able to play around and do what you want with the object in javascript

Comment: Exactly this is the information that I requested.
Thanks.